# Special Characters (InDesign) Total pages marker?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typography, master-page

Is there a special character marker for Total Pages? I can use a marker on my master page for current page where it will say `A`, but if I want it to say `A of 3` (3 being the total number of pages) is there a marker to count all the pages in your document?

I know I could type 3 in there but if I add pages I have to go back and re-edit the master page. Seeing if there is a smarter way to go about this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That is more or less what I was getting at thank you1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define text variable containing *last page number*, which may, or may not, be equivalent to total number of pages. In the case, when your document has more than one section, it won't work. Then some other means to get total pages number will be required—like dedicated script.

Comment: It's my pleasure :}